# error Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field while inserting result of query into column in mysql

Tags: mysql, insert-into

I am trying to find out the center of the polygons of a Shapefile.. and inserting the result into a new column named center..

```
SELECT astext(centroid(`SHAPE`)) FROM `utdpolygon`
```

gives the centroid for all the polygons but when I try to insert the result into new column using

```
INSERT INTO utdpolygon (`center`)
SELECT astext(centroid(`SHAPE`)) FROM `utdpolygon
```

` 
I got this error

> Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field.

I searched for questions which pointed to similar error but they did not help.
I gave point as type for center and later changed it to geometry because type for shape is geometry but that too doesn't help.

Comment: What is the `datatype` of `center`?

Comment: @Crazy2crack its point..

Comment: What is the value of `centroid` that you are getting?

Comment: @Crazy2crack the value of the centroid are longitude and latitude example point(75.00 22.00).

Answer (score 1):

```
use "org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatialDialect" 
insted of "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect".
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your code, first, you're trying to use an INSERT to change the value of the `center` column - you're not inserting new rows you're updating existing ones, so you need to change it to an UPDATE.

Then the values for the `center` column need to be geometry values not text values, so you need to use ST_GeometryFromText (or one of its synonyms) to get a geometry, although in your case the value you're using from the centroid function actually is a geometry, so you could just use it directly, otherwise you're converting it to text and then back to a geometry.

So - either of these UPDATEs will do what you want (the second one is better, I just kept the first one to show the point about creating a geometry when you have a text POINT):

```
UPDATE utdpolygon
SET `center` = ST_GeometryFromText(astext(centroid(`SHAPE`)));
```

or

```
UPDATE utdpolygon
SET `center` = centroid(`SHAPE`);
```

I'm assuming that you have already added the `center` column to the table because you replied above saying that its data type is POINT - if not you'll need to add it first with an ALTER TABLE.